# Problems extracting data from array

Tags: php, arrays

this code...

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json';
$getfield = '?screen_name=bvb';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();

$twitter_array = json_decode($response);

var_dump($twitter_array);
```

gives me this array:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 14173315
        [id_str] => 14173315
        [name] => NBC News
        [screen_name] => NBCNews
        [location] => New York, NY
        [description] => The leading source of global news and information for more than 75 years. Facebook: https://anything Snapchat: https://anything
        [url] => http://anything
        [entities] => stdClass Object (
            [url] => stdClass Object (
                [urls] => Array (
                    [0] => stdClass Object (
                        [url] => http://anything
                        [expanded_url] => http://NBCNews.com
                        [display_url] => NBCNews.com
                        [indices] => Array (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 22
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        [description] => stdClass Object (
            [urls] => Array (
                [0] => stdClass Object (
                    [url] => https://anything
                    [expanded_url] => https://www.facebook.com/NBCNews
                    [display_url] => facebook.com/NBCNews...
```

I am desperately trying to get this data saved into some variables, like `$twitter_array[0]->name;` without success. Can you tell me what I am doing wroing?

Comment: Is it coming in JSON format? If so, are you converting it?

Comment: I have just updated my question with more of my code...

Comment: You already have it in a variable it seems? `echo $twitter_array[0]->name;` should print `NBC News` for example.

Comment: *FYI* `json_decode($json, true)` will convert everything to array instead of object

Comment: guess I had a simple typo in my code. yes, working! shame on me. sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: If error cause is a typo - remove this question.